# Not reading a vowel at the first of the loop

Tags: python, character

My program is suppose to get an alphabetic character from the user and determine if it is a vowel, consonant, space, or illegal character.

It says it is a consonant if I input 'a' when ran. User only inputs one character. The space part of the loop works, but everything else is a consonant when I enter it.

```
myvar = raw_input("Enter an alpabetic character: ")

if myvar == ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
    print "Your character", myvar, "is a vowel"
elif myvar == " ":
    print "Your character", myvar, "is a space"
elif myvar != "a, e, i, o, u, ,":
    print "Your character", myvar, "is a consonant"
else:
    print "Ooops! I think you've messed up"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your comparisons are incorrect.

```
myvar == ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
```

This compares `myvar` to the tuple `("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")`. I think you want something more like

```
if myvar in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
```

This will check if `myvar` appears *in* the tuple containing your vowels.

Using this methodology, you can adjust your consonant check to read:

```
if myvar not in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
```

As you currently have it, you are checking if `myvar` is equal to the string `"a, e, i, o, u, ,"`

An edit: You could also convert your tuples to lists `["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]` and keep the same checks.

Comment: you could have kept the tuples... `myvar in (...)`.